# Create checkbox mecanism with Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

How can you create a checkbox like component with Fabric JS? More like to click on the image, and to set the opacity to 0. If you click again, to set the opacity to 1.

Here is my code:

For the checkbox image:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33281.svg', (image) => {
    image.scale(0.35);
    image.set({
        left: 152,
        top: 120,
        hoverCursor: 'default',
        selectable: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        hasControls: false,
        lockMovementX: true,
        lockMovementY: true

    })
    if(image.onselect === true ) {
        image.set().opacity = 0;
    }
    canvas.add(image);
});
```

The box where the image is put:

```
function addBox(left, top, width, height) {
    const o = new fabric.Rect({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        fill: boxFill,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        centeredRotation: true,
        snapAngle: 45,
        selectable: true,
        type: 'box',
        id: generateId()
    })
    
    if(image.onselect === true ) {
        image.set().opacity = 0;
    }
     
    canvas.add(o)
    canvas.getObjects().map(o => {
        o.hasControls = false
        o.lockMovementX = true
        o.lockMovementY = true

        o.borderColor = '#38A62E'
        o.borderScaleFactor = 2.5
    })
    canvas.selection = false
    canvas.hoverCursor = 'pointer'
    canvas.discardActiveObject()
    canvas.renderAll()
    return o
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a way to make the image appear and dissapear when you click on it ( using opacity or something similarly) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you and many who want to add Event on objects.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

function drawCheckbox(left,right, width, height){
    var imgClass = new fabric.Image.fromURL('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33281.svg',function(img){

    img.width = width; 
    img.height = height; 
    img.left = left; 
    img.top = right; 
    img.hasControls = false

    img.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if(e.target.opacity <= 0.5){
    e.target.opacity = 1;
    }else{
    e.target.opacity = 0.4;
    }
    canvas.renderAll();

    });
    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.renderAll();

  })
  }
  
  drawCheckbox(0,0, 100,100)
  drawCheckbox(100,100, 100,100)
  drawCheckbox(200,200, 100,100)
```

```css
body {
    background-color:silver;
}
canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"> </script>

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is there a way to change the position of the image, within the parameters, and not inside it's function?

Comment: Do you mean parameter to mousedown event ? 

or you want to create a whole checkbox image with parameterized function ?

Comment: A whole checkbox image with parameterized function.

Comment: Answer is updated  please check if you are expecting same.